# If $G$ is a topological group then $M(X,G)$ inherits a (topological) group structure.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

i hope you're having a good day. I'm reading Algebraic Topology From a Homotopical Viewpoint [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0013OZ2QY) and in section 2.3 the authors define a group structure in the space of continuous functions from $X$ to $G$, denoted by $M(X,G)$ and equipped with the compact-open topology. The operation in $M(X,G)$ is defined as follows:
$$
\cdot_M \colon M(X,G) \times M(X,G) \to M(X,G)
$$
$$
(f,g) \mapsto f(x)\cdot_G g(x)$$
It is an excercise to show that if $G$ is a topological group, this operation is a group operation and that it is continuous. How can i show the continuity part?
A hint is the following:
If $X,Y,Z$ are spaces and if $f \colon X \to Y$ is a continuous function then the induced map
$$
f^{\ast} \colon M(Y,Z) \to M(X,Z)
$$
given by composition is continuous. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours trying i have got that this is indeed a direct consecuence of the hint. Consider the following diagram:
$$
M(X,G) \times M(X,G) \xrightarrow{A} M(X,G\times G) \xrightarrow{B} M(X,G)
$$
$$
(f,g) \mapsto (X \xrightarrow{(f,g)}G \times G) \mapsto (X \xrightarrow{(f,g)}G \times G \xrightarrow{\cdot_G }G)
$$
From the hint and the fact that $G$ is a topological group we get that $B$ is continuous. And it is easy to check that $\cdot_M$ factors through $A$ and $B$. It only remains to show that $A$ is continuous but this is easy using the definition of the compact-open topology.